# What is the source of the TypeError given that the proper result is still being returned in Python script?

Tags: python, json, parsing, typeerror

I am currently trying to grab a value from a bit of JSON such as this:

```
bitly_data = "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/link/clicks?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&link=http://bit.ly/TCATL"
```

(when read, this data looks like `{"status_code": 200, "data": {"units": -1, "tz_offset": -4, "unit": "day", "link_clicks": 390}, "status_txt": "OK"}`)

I then read the data and attempt to save just the integer value after `link_clicks` as the variable `clicks`:

```
src = urllib2.urlopen(bitly_data)
clicks = json.load(src)
clicks = clicks['data']['link_clicks']
print clicks
```

The correct value for `clicks` is printed (390), though I get a TypeError: `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

The whole traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/Zach/Dropbox/bitly/bit.py", line 33, in settings
    clicks = clicks['data']['link_clicks']
```

I am mostly confused as to why, despite the error, I am having the correct value returned. I tried rewriting the problematic line as `clicks = clicks['data']['link_clicks'] or 0` but to no avail. I also tried making it into an `if statement` like,

```
if clicks['data']['link_clicks'] == None:
     clicks = 0
else:
     clicks = clicks['data']['link_clicks']
```

But again this had no effect.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It is `clicks['data']` that is `None`, not `clicks = clicks['data']['link_clicks']`, which explains why your if statement doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- I'm not too familiar with json, but my impression was that it couldn't store values like `None` -- Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: Also, this isn't reproducible code. `urllib2.urlopen(bitly_data)` doesn't work with the `bitly_data` you're providing (gives `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'timeout'`)- did you mean that `bitly_data` is what it is supposed to return?

Comment: @DavidRobinson you are exactly right; changing my if statement to ``if clicks['data'] == None:`` did the trick. Many thanks for your quick help.

Comment: I really have no idea how this code could print the correct result after having an (apparently) unhandled `TypeError`.  Either there's more you're not showing here, or you've somehow found a bug in the interpretter (as far as I can see)

Comment: @mgilson: JSON has a `null` type that `json.loads` turns into `None`. Try: `import json; print json.loads("[null]")`.

Comment: I am sorry. I am grabbing the JSON from a URL (obviously) so tried to simplify it. I updated my answer with the exact code.

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- Thanks.  I didn't know that :).  I'll try to keep that in mind if I ever decide to use `json` (I've never really found a need for it when `pickle` is so easy -- and I don't usually need to transfer data from one language to another.

Comment: @mgilson: JSON's especially useful for communicating between languages, but I also find it easier to read than pickle, and easier for non-programmers to understand. Just a thought!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in this case, the JSON that is returned is:

```
{u'status_code': 403, u'data': None, u'status_txt': u'INVALID_ACCESS_TOKEN'}
```

This is probably due to your URL not having a proper access token:

```
https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/link/clicks?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&link=http://bit.ly/TCATL
```

Notice how it says `access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`: this might be from a demo or tutorial that expected you to put your specific API access token in there.

As you note in the comments, one short term fix is to put `if clicks['data'] == None`, but you'll probably want to fix the issue with your API access token.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your first comment did the trick. (I got an access token, though I didn't want to post it online which is why I initially just posted the JSON output)

Comment: @zch: That makes sense, but the JSON output can't be what it is getting in this instance or it wouldn't give you this error. Perhaps you could put a `print clicks` line right *before* the `clicks = clicks['data']['link_clicks']` statement. (There might be a different accessibility issue than your access token, like a 404 error)

Comment: That was my confusion as well. adding ``print`` returned two lines, which is interesting. One is ``{u'status_code': 200, u'data': {u'units': -1, u'tz_offset': -4, u'unit': u'day', u'link_clicks': 390}, u'status_txt': u'OK'}`` and the other, more intriguing, ``{u'status_code': 404, u'data': None, u'status_txt': u'NOT_FOUND'}`` – what could be causing the ``404`` error?

Comment: And when I type the URL I gave above (``api-ssl.bitly.com...`` with my access token), I only see that first line – no error. Thought this may be worth mentioning. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @zch: Likely the `link=` parameter- perhaps it refers to a link that doesn't exist.

Comment: @zch: Does this code get called multiple times in your program?

Comment: It should be equal to what comes after the ``http://bit.ly/`` (such as ``TCATL`` in the examples above). I added ``print`` just now to confirm and it printed ``TCATL``

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18891/discussion-between-david-robinson-and-zch)

Comment: It does not, no. The variable ``link`` is established in a function earlier on, but I have made it part of the URL in the function that is above and the one returning the error. Other than that variable, everything else is only called once and is called in this function.